# The fair soup division and approximating numbers

Tags: polynomials, approximation

Recently [The Vee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/65332/the-vee) confessed:

> Literally every time I'm serving some soup I'm thinking of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993836/the-soup-problem-how-to-asymptotically-fairly-split-a-geometric-series-and-a-co) little mathematical problem I devised.

Solving the problem, I introduced the following notion.

A number $q\in (1/2, 1)$ is *approximating*, if there exist non-negative numbers $A$ and $N$ such that for each $x_0\in [0,A]$ there exist $n\le N$ and a polynomial $P(x)$ of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n \pm x^i$ such that $P(1)=0$ and $|x_0-P(q)|\le Aq^n$. We [can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993836/the-soup-problem-how-to-asymptotically-fairly-split-a-geometric-series-and-a-co/4001270#4001270) that The Vee’s problem has a solution for each approximating number $q$. This poses my question

> Which $q\in (1/2,1)$ are approximating?

Thanks.

*My try.*

I wrote a short [paper](https://mega.nz/file/M1RWERwL#-xleLdm6gU_YZ00r6k7BgK3sjPsfbhdGxCFP-3KkBgg) on The Vee's problem and approximating numbers. There is shown that each $q\in (q_\infty,1)$ is approximating, where $q_\infty=0.5845751\dots$ is a unique positive root of a polynomial $Q_\infty(x)=x^4+x^3+2x^2-1$.

I am going to give a talk on the paper at [Western Ukrainian online mathematical seminar](http://www.math.lviv.ua/seminar/index.php) at Monday, February 1, at 15:05 [GMT+2](https://time.is/en/GMT+2). I hope the talk will be recorded and then put at Youtube.

Comment: (+1) Going above and beyond in "what have you tried" and providing context :)